# Mounting a hidden partition in windows using C# or C++ program

Tags: c++, windows, mount, disk-partitioning, fat32

I have a FAT32 partition that is hidden. I like to copy files to it from a Windows application implemented in C# or C++.

The examples I have seen end up creating a drive in Explorer while the hidden partition is mounted.

Is there a way to mount this partition programmatically without it being visible in Windows Explorer?
Then I like to copy files to it and unmount it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Depending on how you've hidden the partition, it might already be mounted and available via a path like \\.\Volume{GUID}

Comment: This is a hidden bootable GPT style partition. Can you point me to examples how to use above naming convention and see contents of the partition? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CreateSymbolicLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363866.aspx) did the trick. You can pass path of a volume to it. It lets you create a symbolic link to hidden partitions. You can create sym links to specific files as well as directories with it.
The path of hidden partition should be passed like "**\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition1\dirA\dirB**".